# R: object .... not found

Tags: r

So I'm trying to process the data ("final_ts") in order to make a forecast for the time series using kernel functions and doing parallel computing. The analysis is made this way: 1) analyse the empirical time series, 2) run a standard variable
selection to subset only those variables and their time-lags that provide the best validation error. 3) Run the same analysis described above to choose the optimal regularization parameters and kernel function of the regularized algorithm. As a result I show the RMSE (root mean squared error).

The code is not mine, and I'm trying to set it without problems, but as I do not have so much experience, I can't understand how to solve (I've spent 2 days trying to find the solution so if you help me I would be so grateful) the problem which occured: "The object '....' not found".

So the MAIN CODE looks like this (I'll try to make explanation on what happens, please don't judge me):

```
#download the libraries:

rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)) 
suppressMessages(library(Matrix))
suppressMessages(library(quantreg))
suppressMessages(library(parallel))
suppressMessages(library(compiler))
suppressMessages(library(lars))
suppressMessages(library(elasticnet))
suppressMessages(library(caret))
options(warn=-1)

#####################################################################################
#Download the sources (I'll show them in the end as a code)

###########Take the file###
ShowPlot = FALSE
lags = TRUE
ModelName = 'final_ts'
FileName = paste(ModelName, '.txt', sep = '')
########Calculate the logspace and the standard error functions #################
logspace <- function(d1, d2, n) exp(log(10)*seq(d1, d2, length.out=n)) 
std_err <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
############# Choose the kernel function: we have 4 of them, but we try the second one #####
Kernel.Options = c('Exponential.Kernel', 'Epanechnikov.Kernel', 'TriCubic.Kernel', 'Matern.Kernel')
Regression.Kernel = Kernel.Options[1]

############# Choose the parameters for cross validation ####
lambda = logspace(-3,0,15) 
if(Regression.Kernel == 'Exponential.Kernel'){
  tht = seq(from = 0., to = 10, length = 30)         
}else{
  tht = seq(from = 0.1, to = 3, length = 20)     
}
parameters_on_grid = expand.grid(tht, lambda)     
### Read Time series
d = as.matrix(read.table(FileName, header= T))
######################
original.Embedding = c('Pro', 'Syn','Piceu')
original.TargetList = original.Embedding
d = d[, original.Embedding]
#### Here you take combinations of lags (best lag are 1 - 2) #####
x.lag = 1; y.lag = 2; z.lag = 1
sp.lag.selection = c(x.lag, y.lag, z.lag)
lagged.time.series = make.lagged.ts(d, sp.lag.selection)
d = lagged.time.series$time.series
original.col = lagged.time.series$original.variables
if(lags == TRUE){ var.sel = original.col; }else{ var.sel = colnames(d)}
##### Names and embedding in the laged dataset
if(lags == TRUE){ colnames(d) = Embedding =  TargetList = LETTERS[1:ncol(d)]}else{
  Embedding =  TargetList = original.Embedding
}
##### length of training and test set (2 points for testing, 28 - for training)
length.testing = 2
length.training = nrow(d) - length.testing
#### Preserve training for the interactions
ts.train.preserved = d[1:length.training, var.sel]
std.ts.train = Standardizza(ts.train.preserved)
#### Preserve testing for the test (you want your algorithm to learn the real structure of the model)
ts.test.preserved = d[(length.training + 1):nrow(d), var.sel]
#### Training set:
d.training = Standardizza(d[1:length.training, ])
#### You now need to standardize the test set using mean and sd of the training set
d.testing = Standardizza.test(ts.test.preserved,ts.train.preserved)
############## Prepare for parallel computing
Lavoratori = detectCores() - 2
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(Lavoratori, setup_strategy = "sequential")
####
RegressionType = ELNET_fit_

alpha = 0.85

### should you compute all the variables or not?
BestModel = BestModelLOOCV(cl, d.training, TargetList, Embedding, parameters_on_grid, RegressionType,alpha)
```

I also found a fourmula for calculation of kernel function (it may be put in a SPECIAL r (SOURCE 1)):

```
Exponential.Kernel <- function(dst, theta){
  dbar <- mean(dst)
  krnl <- exp(-theta*dst/dbar)
  return(krnl)
}
Exponential.Kernel <- cmpfun(Exponential.Kernel)
```

The formulas for finding the best leave-one-out cross-validation parameters is below (SOURCE 2):

```
########################### Cross Validation (Leave-one-out) ##################################

BestModelLOOCV <- function(cl, X, TargetList, Embedding, grid, RegressionType,alpha){
  mine_output = Jacobian_(cl, X, TargetList, Embedding, grid, RegressionType,alpha)
  theta_opt = mine_output$th
  lambda_opt = mine_output$lm
 mine_c0  = mine_output$c0
  mine_output = mine_output$J
  
  J_ = list()
  C0_ = do.call(cbind, lapply(1:ncol(X), function(x, M) unlist(M[[x]]), mine_c0))
  colnames(C0_) = sapply(TargetList,function(x) paste("c0_", x, sep = ""))
  for(k in 1:(nrow(X) - 1)){
    J_[[k]] = do.call(rbind, lapply(1:ncol(X), function(x, M, i) unlist(M[[x]][i,]), mine_output, k))
    rownames(J_[[k]]) = Embedding
    colnames(J_[[k]]) = Embedding
    
  }
  BestCoefficients = list()
  BestCoefficients$J = J_
  BestCoefficients$c0 = C0_
  BestParameters = list()
  BestParameters$BestTH = theta_opt
  BestParameters$BestLM = lambda_opt
  return(list(BestCoefficients = BestCoefficients, BestParameters = BestParameters))
}
  
#####Compute the jacobian
Jacobian_ <- function(cl, X, TargetList, Embedding, grid, RegressionType,alpha){
  J = c0 = list()
  th = lm = c()
  n_ = 1
  FUN = match.fun(RegressionType)
  for(trg in TargetList){
    RegularizedParameters <- LOOCrossValidation(cl, X, trg, Embedding, grid, RegressionType,alpha)
    ########## Now compute the optimum regularized coefficients
    J[[n_]]  = FUN(X, trg, Embedding, RegularizedParameters$BestTH, RegularizedParameters$BestLM,alpha)
    th = c(th, RegularizedParameters$BestTH)
    lm = c(lm, RegularizedParameters$BestLM)
    c0[[n_]] = J[[n_]]$c0
    J[[n_]] = J[[n_]][-1]
    n_ = n_ + 1
  }
  return(list(J = J, c0 = c0, th = th, lm = lm))
}
```

In order to compute the elastic-net regularization function you may use this formula (SOURCE 3):

```
ELNET_fit_ <- function(time.series, targ_col, Embedding, theta, lambda,alp){
  Edim <- length(Embedding)
  coeff_names <- sapply(colnames(time.series),function(x) paste("d", targ_col, "d", x, sep = ""))
  block <- cbind(time.series[2:dim(time.series)[1],targ_col],time.series[1:(dim(time.series)[1]-1),])
  block <- as.data.frame(apply(block, 2, function(x) (x-mean(x))/sd(x)))
  
  lib <- 1:dim(block)[1]
  pred <- 1:dim(block)[1]
  
  coeff <- array(0,dim=c(length(pred),Edim + 1))
  colnames(coeff) <- c('c0', coeff_names)
  coeff <- as.data.frame(coeff)
  
  for (ipred in 1:length(pred)){
    libs = lib[-pred[ipred]]
    q <- matrix(as.numeric(block[pred[ipred],2:dim(block)[2]]),
                ncol=Edim, nrow=length(libs), byrow = T)
    distances <- sqrt(rowSums((block[libs,2:dim(block)[2]] - q)^2))
    ### Kernel
    Krnl = match.fun(Regression.Kernel)
    Ws = Krnl(distances, theta)
    ############ Fit function
    x = as.matrix(block[libs,2:dim(block)[2]])
    y = as.matrix(block[libs,1])
    x = x[seq_along(y), ]
    y = y[seq_along(y)]
    Ws = Ws[seq_along(y)]
    x = Ws * cbind(1, x)
    y = Ws * y
    fit <- enet(x, y, lambda = lambda, normalize = TRUE, intercept = FALSE)
    coeff[ipred,] <- predict(fit, s = alp, type="coefficients", mode="fraction")$coefficients 
  }
  return(coeff)
}

ELNET_fit_ <- cmpfun(ELNET_fit_)
```

The auxiliary formulas for computation are as follows (SOURCE 4):

```
TakeLag <- function(X, species.to.lag, num.lag){
  tmp = matrix(0, nrow(X), num.lag)
  tmp[,1] = X[,species.to.lag]
  tmp[1, 1] = NA
  tmp[2:nrow(X), 1] = X[1:(nrow(X) - 1), species.to.lag]
  if(num.lag > 1){
    for(lag. in 2:num.lag){
      tmp[,lag.] = X[,species.to.lag]
      tmp[1, lag.] = NA
      tmp[2:nrow(X), lag.] = tmp[1:(nrow(tmp) - 1), lag.-1]
    }
  }
  tmp
}
make.lagged.ts <- function(X,sp.lag.selection ){
  ### X = time series
  ### sp.lag is a vector whose entry are the lags of each variable
  ### e.g., sp.lag = c(x.lag, y.lag, ..., u.lag)
  s = list()
  for(i in 1:length(sp.lag.selection)){
    Lag.sp = TakeLag(X, original.Embedding[i], sp.lag.selection[i])
    s[[i]] = cbind(X[,original.Embedding[i]], Lag.sp)
  }
  X = do.call(cbind,s)
  ### Remove the NA
  X = X[-c(1:max(sp.lag.selection)),]
  ### Save the position of the unlagged variables
  original.col = c()
  for(k in 1:length(sp.lag.selection)){
    if(k == 1){ original.col = c(original.col, 1)}else{
      num.lags = sum(unlist(lapply(1:(k-1), function(x,X) X[x], sp.lag.selection)))
      original.col = c(original.col, k + num.lags )
    }
  }
  return(list(time.series = X, original.variables = original.col))
}

take.coeff <- function(X, col.to.extract, original.emb){
  ### To use when prediction are made using lagged variables
  ### Take as input the sequence X of Jacobian along the attractor
  ### and the species to look at
  ### return a new sequence of Jacobian of the interaction among those species
  m = lapply(1:length(X$J), function(t, M, specie) M$J[[t]][specie,specie], 
                X, col.to.extract)
  for(i in 1:length(m)){
    colnames(m[[i]]) = rownames(m[[i]]) =original.emb
  }
  return(m)
}

Standardizza <- function(X){
  ### This return y = (x-meanx)/stdx
  for(i in 1:ncol(X)){
    X[,i] = (X[,i]- mean(X[,i]))/sd(X[,i])
  }
  return(X)
}
Standardizza.test <- function(X, Y){
  ### X = test set
  ### Y = training set
  ### This return y = (x-meanY)/stdY
  for(i in 1:ncol(X)){
    X[,i] = (X[,i]- mean(Y[,i]))/sd(Y[,i])
  }
  return(X)
}
###########################
#### Here you compute the quality of the forecast as mean correlation coefficient
```

The problem in the main code sounds like: object 'Regression.Kernel' not found, but I see it in the code, it's written. Maybe the problem is connected with the type of it? But if I take away the quotes in order to make it a "closure", I cannot impose the function restrictions.

Please, help me if you can as I don't know how to solve.

The original dataset ("final_ts.txt"):

```
decy Temp CTD_S OxFix Pro Syn Piceu Naneu
  2011.74221     27.60333     36.20700     27.26667  58638.33333  13107.00000    799.66667    117.66667
  2011.74401     26.97950     36.13400     27.05000  71392.50000  13228.50000   1149.00000    116.50000
  2011.74617     24.99750     35.34450     24.80000 264292.00000  27514.00000   2434.50000    132.50000
  2011.74692     24.78400     35.25800     25.82500 208996.50000  39284.00000   3761.75000    220.75000
  2011.74774     27.34225     35.86800     27.82500 114617.25000  23115.00000   2337.00000    139.75000
  2011.74950     26.47875     36.18175     27.20000  97008.00000   9775.75000    855.50000     77.50000
  2011.75583     26.86500     36.14575     27.47500  76255.00000  10226.75000    783.00000     99.50000
  2011.75654     27.04550     36.04950     27.60000  95017.75000  10546.25000    915.25000     77.75000
  2011.75962     27.06567     36.46367     26.56667  75750.00000  10194.33333    687.00000     44.00000
  2011.76101     27.44700     36.48150     27.90000  38556.50000   8204.75000    791.25000    118.75000
  2011.76169     27.32325     36.50075     27.80000  29848.50000   8995.50000    727.00000    159.25000
  2011.76245     26.87050     36.57350     26.40000  36323.50000  10897.00000    792.00000     87.50000
  2011.76349     27.43900     36.89325     27.90000  17308.50000   9678.50000    559.00000    149.00000
  2011.77171     26.74050     36.90550     26.10000  20976.50000   7516.00000    489.50000     41.50000
  2011.77224     26.53500     36.77500     27.22500  27229.00000   7578.00000    606.75000    159.50000
  2011.77288     26.65450     36.78500     27.32500  37897.50000  10493.50000   1008.75000    209.50000
  2011.77444     27.24150     36.73800     26.80000  15551.00000   8159.50000    479.00000     70.50000
  2011.77505     26.67560     36.74240     27.30000  27887.80000   5290.80000    510.00000    101.20000
  2011.77568     27.65125     36.69225     28.10000  12850.00000   9944.75000    640.75000    120.00000
  2011.77693     28.11500     36.32750     27.85000   5694.00000  10288.50000    507.00000     32.00000
  2011.77751     28.61950     36.26325     28.72500  20486.75000  10465.00000    430.50000     82.75000
  2011.77814     28.60425     36.23100     28.70000  27974.50000   6977.25000    554.00000     80.50000
  2011.77968     28.47200     35.69000     28.40000 126778.00000   2840.00000    537.00000     27.00000
  2011.78087     28.89400     35.60650     28.35000  49250.00000   5533.00000   1004.00000      5.50000
  2011.78190     28.74100     35.46200     28.80000  35698.00000   1298.00000    308.00000     23.00000
  2011.78713     28.80500     35.50100     28.70000  99450.00000   5410.00000    637.50000     50.50000
  2011.78887     28.39250     35.90900     28.25000 116562.00000   3758.50000    582.50000     60.00000
  2011.79078     28.10550     36.40150     28.20000  13403.00000  11285.00000    472.00000     73.50000
  2011.79261     27.25650     36.78350     27.45000  11205.00000  10576.00000    630.00000     74.00000
```

Please, help if you have any guess as I don't have an idea what has gone wrong.

Comment: Parsing through this extremely long question ... can you explain why `y[seq_along(y)]` would in effect be anything other than an identity? I have not found an example where `identical(y, y[seq_along(y)])` is not always true.

Comment: How exactly are you running this code? Are all these code blocks in one large file? This is way too much code to expect someone to go though all at once. Can you make the code more minimal? Take out any non-essential functions that still triggers the same error?

Comment: You will need to run the code defining the `Exponential.Kernel` function before the `ELNET_fit_` function, otherwise `match.fun` won't find it. `"Exponential.Kernel"` is the value of `Regression.Kernel`. That might be the cause of the error message.

Comment: @r2evans, thank you for reply! Unfortunately, the code is not mine (as it's written in the beginning), so I don't know.

Comment: @McFlick no, the main code is the only code I run, others are the sources with functions for this code to run. So they may be put in separate r studio files to source from

Comment: @Andrew Gustar it didn't help, as It runs before (look at the first part of the code). It is called before by `Kernel.Options = c('Exponential.Kernel', 'Epanechnikov.Kernel', 'TriCubic.Kernel', 'Matern.Kernel')
Regression.Kernel = Kernel.Options[1]` and ELNET_fit_ is called after, right before the `BestModelLOOCV` function

Comment: @r2evans I have got rid of parts which are unnecessary, so it may look easier. I'm not sure that the reason is in `y[seq_along(y)]`. Maybe you have other options?

Comment: @Andrew Gustar, thank you for reply, I have got rid of parts which are unnecessary, so it may look easier. Please, look and tell, if you have any guess, what could go wrong with the code.

Comment: @MrFlick I have got rid of parts which are unnecessary, please take a look.

Comment: If these are separate files, where exactly is the `source()`-ing happening? If objects aren't being found, then the sourcing is probably not happening or happening in the wrong place.

Comment: @MrFlick The sources are imported correctly, if I run the source path, everything is fine, no problem occurs

Comment: Well, running the `source()` without errors does not mean that everything worked correctly. The calls to `source()` will place objects in certain environments. You need to make sure they are going in the environment you expect. When an object doesn't exist in the correct environment, you get the "object not found" error.

Comment: @MrFlick, I put everything in one file, and changed the `Regression.Kernel` to the `Exponential.Kernel` in match.fun(). I deleted the sources part from the MAIN code and put all the codes from the source packages in one file (The MAIN code). I also put the `Exponential.Kernel` function inside the `ELNET_fit_ function` and the code found the `Exponential.Kernel` function, but for now it can't find the enet function, which is a part of the `elasticnet` package which I downloaded beforehand. So I don't know what the problem is.